# moduli in SSL certificates

Tags: encryption, rsa, tls

this is normally seen in a typical SSL certificate. For the modulus, I know that it is represented in hexadecimal form, but why is there a semicolon (:) after every group of 2 digits?

```
Public-Key: (2048 bit) Modulus:
00:bf:e7:7c:28:1d:c8:78:a7:13:1f:cd:2b:f7:63:
2c:89:0a:74:ab:62:c9:1d:7c:62:eb:e8:fc:51:89:
b3:45:0e:a4:fa:b6:06:de:b3:24:c0:da:43:44:16:
e5:21:cd:20:f0:58:34:2a:12:f9:89:62:75:e0:55:
8c:6f:2b:0f:44:c2:06:6c:4c:93:cc:6f:98:e4:4e:
3a:79:d9:91:87:45:cd:85:8c:33:7f:51:83:39:a6:
9a:60:98:e5:4a:85:c1:d1:27:bb:1e:b2:b4:e3:86:
a3:21:cc:4c:36:08:96:90:cb:f4:7e:01:12:16:25:
90:f2:4d:e4:11:7d:13:17:44:cb:3e:49:4a:f8:a9:
a0:72:fc:4a:58:0b:66:a0:27:e0:84:eb:3e:f3:5d:
5f:b4:86:1e:d2:42:a3:0e:96:7c:75:43:6a:34:3d:
6b:96:4d:ca:f0:de:f2:bf:5c:ac:f6:41:f5:e5:bc:
fc:95:ee:b1:f9:c1:a8:6c:82:3a:dd:60:ba:24:a1:
eb:32:54:f7:20:51:e7:c0:95:c2:ed:56:c8:03:31:
96:c1:b6:6f:b7:4e:c4:18:8f:50:6a:86:1b:a5:99:
d9:3f:ad:41:00:d4:2b:e4:e7:39:08:55:7a:ff:08:
30:9e:df:9d:65:e5:0d:13:5c:8d:a6:f8:82:0c:61:
c8:6b
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

Comment: This question appears to be **off-topic** because it is not about cryptography as defined in our [help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 6):

To make it easier for humans to read.

Comment: **This is comment, but not an answer.** Let’s be honest: is this the outcome when you [“*Write to the best of your ability*”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), as explained in our help center? To turn this comment into an actual answer, you should – at least – add a link to the reference/paper where this formatting is defined, and quote the relevant part of that reference/paper.